# Does writing to standard output allocate memory?

Tags: c, memory, stdout

I'm new in C programming so I'm curious about the notion of memory allocation.

Does writing to standard output allocate memory?

For example:

```
    write(fd, 'X', 1); //where fd is a specific file descriptor (not 1, 2 or 0)
```

In this case this code add an 'X' character in the file correspondent to the fd, so memory is allocated in the specific file.
But here:

```
    write(1, 'X', 1);
```

Is memory allocated? If yes, where? If no, why and how is 'X' displayed in the standard output?

Comment: This is completely implementation defined. Why are you asking?

Comment: You can check on your particular system, and if you use linux or OS X you can do it quickly and easily with valgrind.

Comment: It's new for me, I'm just curious about how it work.

Comment: Not only is it implementation-defined, but on any given implementation it may depend on how you run the program.

Comment: You don't need to care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this allocate memory? It depends on the OS. The OS may need to create some internal temporary buffers to hold the data, but then again, it might use some preallocated space for the data. There’s no way to know without cracking open the OS and seeing how it works, and the answer might differ from system to system or even from run to run.

Does this allocate memory *that you need to deallocate?* Nope! The OS cleans up its own messes, and so from your perspective you don’t need to free anything. Generally, you only need to free memory that you explicitly allocate, and system calls like these don’t assign that responsibility to you.

Should this matter? Probably not. Typically, you’d only worry about this if you were transferring colossal amounts of memory and seeing an associated performance hit that led you to investigate what aaa going on.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I wanted.